# Responsive breaks not working in jQuery grid-tab

Tags: jquery

I am using the [jQuery grid-tab plugin](https://github.com/gopalraju/gridtab). In the below code I used the responsive breakpoints, but it is not working, under small screens, that is under 768px, the grid layout is showing the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gridtab-1').gridtab({
    grid: 4,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 991,
      settings: {
        grid: 3,
      }
    }, {
      breakpoint: 767,
      settings: {
        grid: 2,
      }
    }, {
      breakpoint: 520,
      settings: {
        grid: 1
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: That plugin seems a little outdated as it's not been updated in years. Check the console for errors to ensure it's compatible with the version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: no errors shown up in the console.